# Find Local IP of VPN Client

Tags: ip, openvpn

I have two servers server A and server B. Server B is a VPN for server A. How do I find the local IP of server A on server B when server A is behind server B's VPN? I think it should be listed when I issue the command 'ifconfig' but I'm not exactly sure which IP I am looking for at that point.

output from ifconfig -a

```
gre0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-8C-B9-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          NOARP  MTU:1476  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

gretap0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1476  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

ip6tnl0   Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          NOARP  MTU:1460  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:377 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:377 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:76799 (76.7 KB)  TX bytes:76799 (76.7 KB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.1  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8726841 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7897879 errors:0 dropped:22138 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
          RX bytes:6123986424 (6.1 GB)  TX bytes:6479665617 (6.4 GB)

venet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:127.0.0.2  P-t-P:127.0.0.2  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: 2604:180:2:127b::2ed4/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:18726387 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16971835 errors:0 dropped:799 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:13379179118 (13.3 GB)  TX bytes:13281478025 (13.2 GB)

venet0:0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:107.191.96.157  P-t-P:107.191.96.157  Bcast:107.191.96.157  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

Comment: Could you please give us your `ifconfig -a` or `ip a`/`ip l` outputs? We could probably then tell you which interface is the `VPN` one.

Comment: @phk I have edited my question with the ouput from ifconfig -a

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the tag, I'm guessing you're running OpenVPN. OpenVPN uses either tun or tap tunnels, so that'd be `tun0`. Then your local IP (on the VPN) is 10.8.0.1, which is oddly (as in it strikes me as a configuration error) also the peer IP.

BTW: On Linux, `ifconfig` (friends) is basically obsolete and replaced by the `ip` command. `ip addr ls` will give you all the addresses.

Comment: "Then your local IP (on the VPN) is 10.8.0.1, which is oddly (as in it strikes me as a configuration error) also the peer IP." Can you explain that further?

Comment: The address after "P-t-P" is the peer (other side of the tunnel) address. Normally that'd be different—IP addresses are supposed to be unique. So you can, for example, `ping «remote-ip»` to ping across the tuinnel. Both sides of the tunnel are running the same IP address currently (or at least this machine believes so).

Comment: So I probably need to change something in my openvpn config so that they are unique IP's? I am basically trying to ssh into server A directly by forwarding ports and I need to use the localIP of server A behind server B's VPN but I assume this might cause problems if the IP is not unique.

Comment: Yes, that'd fail if the IPs aren't unique as you'd wind up ssh'ing into localhost instead of the other end. You're looking for the `ifconfig` line in your OpenVPN config.

Comment: So we basically should use "ip addr ls label tun0"